# Recursion of rows in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a vba code for recursion of rows in excel. Below is my code. I want to copy few number of rows as a set, not as a individual rows. I have attached the image of how the code should work like. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
For y = 2 To end_IA
    If Worksheets("Task").Cells(y, "A") = "Task1" Then
        Worksheets("Task").Cells(y, "C").Value = nocopies
    End If
    If Worksheets("Task").Cells(y, "A") = "Task2" Then
        Worksheets("Task").Cells(y, "C").Value = nocopies
    End If
    If Worksheets("Task").Cells(y, "A") = "Task3" Then
        Worksheets("Task").Cells(y, "C").Value = nocopies
    End If
Next y

For y = 2 To end_Tasks
    For n = 1 To nocopies

        Worksheets("Task").Cells(y, "A").Copy
        Worksheets("Task").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Data_Sheet").Cells(end_Data + 1, 1)

        Worksheets("Task").Cells(y, "B").Copy
        Worksheets("Task").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Data_Sheet").Cells(end_Data + 1, 2)

        end_Data = end_Data + 1
    Next n

Next y

End Sub
```

Source data:
[image: Data]

Expected result:
[image: Expected result]

Task sheet
Current Result
[image: Current Result]

Comment: What do your original data look like? Please add a picture to your question.

Comment: The first image "Data" is my table (in one worksheet) and now I want to copy only columns A and B to other worksheet based on the count in column C of the data sheet

Comment: What happens if the numbers in column 3 are not all the same?